# Subtracting current time from deadline time in C

Tags: c, datetime, time

I want to write a code as a subproblem of a project that takes input the deadline time of anything in Hours,minutes,seconds and subtracts the current local time and shows it.

I can use the clock() function to get the current time but i don't know how to subtract the input from it because I don't know what's going on inside the clock function, can anybody help?

Comment: How do you think you _can use the clock() function to get the current time_? It _returns an approximation of processor time used by the program_, not the _current local time_.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.